# Excel spreadsheed populate cell based on value of another cell

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, populate

I have a excel spreadsheet that contains a bunch of columns. My first column contains values of mpg(about 300 entries of miles per gallon). What I want to do is populate another column 
based on whether the value of the first cell is greater than or less than 23.5

So basically it looks like this:

```
**A**    **B**
 10 
 15
 29
 14
 32
 24
```

I want column B to be populated depending on if the corresponding cell (eg. A1 > 24.5 so populate B with yes) is greater than 24.5 with yes or no.

Is there a simple function I can use to do it on all the values?
Please do provide detailed instructions since I hardly use excel and I'm lost on this past.

Comment: Do you know how formulas work in Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type `=IF(A2 > 23.5,"yes","no")` into B2. Then double-click the bottom-right corner of the cell (the little box) to fill the rest of the cells.

Comment: Ah thank you! I was trying to get my dataset into the right format and this was easier than I thought. Thanks!